# converting a matrix into a linear format python

Tags: python, matrix

I have several text files in a folder (they are all consistent). Each file contains a matrix (see example below)

[image]

I want to change the format of each file from matrix into a linear format using the python so it can look like the following:

[image]

Can you please kindly assist me with this?

Regards,
Shei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read each file in `pandas` and then use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas-dataframe-melt) to get them into the desired format.

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {'MainID': [1, 2],
        'MainIDDe': ['ABC', 'ABD'],
        'Apple': [10, 9],
        'Banana': [2, 6],
        'Pineapple': [10, 6]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).melt(
    id_vars=["MainID", "MainIDDe"], var_name="Fruits", value_name="Values"
)
print(df)
```

will give

```
   MainID MainIDDe     Fruits  Values
0       1      ABC      Apple      10
1       2      ABD      Apple       9
2       1      ABC     Banana       2
3       2      ABD     Banana       6
4       1      ABC  Pineapple      10
5       2      ABD  Pineapple       6
```